# Scroll bug using UITextView in iOS 8.1 (iPad 2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

The problem which I have is same as: [Smooth UITextView auto scroll to bottom of frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453108/smooth-uitextview-auto-scroll-to-bottom-of-frame-solved)

Basically, when I use the auto scroll feature when appending a text to an existing text in UITextView, the scroll works, but it always goes to top then scroll all the way to bottom (which is a problem for big texts, or a chat room)

When I try the solution of this guy, which was :

```
textview.scrollEnabled= NO;
textview.text = [textview.text stringByAppendingString:createdString];
textview.scrollEnabled= YES;
[textview scrollRangeToVisible:textview.selectedRange];
```

So, I found a bug where it seems that the 'textview.scrollEnabled' never gets back to YES, so the scroll will simply never work.

I either have that weird scrolling where it gets back to top then to bottom or the other bug where the scrolling enabled never gets back to YES.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. 
Get rid of the `textView.scrollEnabled = NO;`.

So your just left with:

```
textview.text = [textview.text stringByAppendingString:createdString];
[textview scrollRangeToVisible:textview.selectedRange]
```

and add this to your viewDidLoad:

```
textview.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem too where scroll works fine in iOS 7 and iOS 9 but not in iOS 8. So, I found solution for scrolling to work in iOS 8 is:

```
NSString *strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your text"];
txtVwObj.text = strValue; // If in your case text needs to give before scroll disable.
txtVwObj.scrollEnabled = NO;

// and set whatever you need for UITextView properties. 
// at last add the following code snippet.
 txtVwObj.scrollEnabled = YES;
 txtVwObj.text = @"";
 txtVwObj.text = [txtVwObj.text stringByAppendingString:strValue];
```

Hope it will help you.